# Problem with changing dynamic text color in react

Tags: reactjs, dynamic, colors, jsx, tailwind-css

I created an array of properties. For every properties there is a color value. While I'm looping the array value in jsx I want to change text color.

Here is the array and the .jsx file where I want to change color

```
const steps = [
  {
    title: 'Step 1',
    color: '#7C3EDA',
    name: 'Medical History',
    source: '/assets/Star2.png',
    desc: "Complete a simple medical history form so your provider can develop the best treatment plan for you. It's fast, easy, and free."
  },
  {
    title: 'Step 2',
    color: '#17CBBE',
    name: 'Online Visit',
    source: '/assets/Star3.png',
    desc: 'Speak to your new healthcare provider licensed to treat your condition with a simple online audio-visual appointment conversation.'
  },
  {
    title: 'Step 3',
    color: '#FF3755',
    name: 'Receive Medications',
    source: '/assets/Star4.png',
    desc: 'If medically appropriate, receive your medication every 30/60/90 days. All GLP-1 Plans come with free shipping directly to your door! Follow up with your provider any time you need assistance.'
  }
]

<div className="py-5 md:py-7 lg:py-20 flex flex-wrap gap-8 justify-center">
  {steps && steps.map((step, index) => (
  <div key={index} className="relative">
    <div className="w-[315px] md:w-[330px] lg:w-[350px] 2xl:w-[380px]">
      <img src={step.source} className="w-full" alt="star" />
    </div>
    <div
      className="absolute top-0 w-[315px] md:w-[330px] lg:w-[350px] 2xl:w-[380px] h-full space-y-2 px-6 py-5 text-center"
    >
      <p className={`font-bold" text-[${step.color}] text-4xl`}>
        {step.title}
      </p>
      <p className="font-medium text-2xl">{step.name}</p>
      <p className="text-[#666666] text-sm md:text-base">{step.desc}</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  ))}
</div>
```

Comment: The issue here is that you are trying to use a variable inside a template literal to get a color. You should use inline styles to dynamically change the color. As @Moshin mentioned you can use a helper function to generate this styles or inline it as `style={{color: step.color, fontWeight: 'bold' ...`

Answer (score 0):

you can use a helper function to generate this styles or inline it as

```
const steps = [
  {
    title: 'Step 1',
    color: '#7C3EDA',
    name: 'Medical History',
    source: '/assets/Star2.png',
    desc: "Complete a simple medical history form so your provider can develop the best treatment plan for you. It's fast, easy, and free."
  },
  {
    title: 'Step 2',
    color: '#17CBBE',
    name: 'Online Visit',
    source: '/assets/Star3.png',
    desc: 'Speak to your new healthcare provider licensed to treat your condition with a simple online audio-visual appointment conversation.'
  },
  {
    title: 'Step 3',
    color: '#FF3755',
    name: 'Receive Medications',
    source: '/assets/Star4.png',
    desc: 'If medically appropriate, receive your medication every 30/60/90 days. All GLP-1 Plans come with free shipping directly to your door! Follow up with your provider any time you need assistance.'
  }
];

const handleColor = (step) => {
  const color = step.color;
  return `text-${color}`;
};

<div className="py-5 md:py-7 lg:py-20 flex flex-wrap gap-8 justify-center">
          {steps && steps.map((step, index) => (
            <div key={index} className="relative">
              <div className="w-[315px] md:w-[330px] lg:w-[350px] 2xl:w-[380px]">
                <img src={step.source} className='w-full' alt="star" />
              </div>
              <div className="absolute top-0 w-[315px] md:w-[330px] lg:w-[350px] 2xl:w-[380px] h-full space-y-2 px-6 py-5 text-center">
                <p className={handleColor(step)}>{step.title}</p>
                <p className='font-medium text-2xl'>{step.name}</p>
                <p className='text-[#666666] text-sm md:text-base'>{step.desc}</p>
              </div>
            </div>
          ))}
        </div>
```

Comment: Thank you for your feedback. the following function worked for me. 
const handleColor = (step) => {
  const color = step.color;
  return `text-[${color}]`;
};

Comment: You're welcome! I'm glad to hear that the function worked for you.